# Set Opacity on CSS Element

Tags: html, css

I'd like the triangle shape at the foot of this page to be a solid colour with no transparency. Is this easy to achieve? I'm just not sure which element to target.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/9/

and my code :

**css**

```
 html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.out{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.in{
    height:75%;
    background-color:#6C2223;
}
.out:before, .out:after, .in:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25%;
    width:100%;
    height:700%;
    background-color:#9A4445;
}
.out:before{
    right:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;

     -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
    transform : rotate(-45deg);
}
.out:after{
    left:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;

    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
    transform : rotate(45deg);
}
.in:after{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:#911618;
    z-index:-1;
}
video{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="in"></div>
    <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/home-vid-img.jpg" id="bgvid">
                <source src="http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/homepage.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/shutterstock_v3702740_4.m4v" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
</div>
```

Can someone assist?

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Comment: The problem is that the video is in the front with `opacity: 0.5`. You should bring `.in:after` in front of the video.

Comment: Let me try that just now & I'll see how it goes :-)

Comment: Hi @Barnee - any chance you could take a look? My efforts so far have failed badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got what you want. Change your CSS code with this ([JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/sKD5z/)):

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.out{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.in{
    height:75%;
    background-color:#6C2223;
}
.out:before, .out:after, .in:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25%;
    width:100%;
    height:700%;
    background-color:#9A4445;
}
.out:before{
    right:50%;

    z-index:20;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;

     -webkit-transform : rotate(-135deg);
    transform : rotate(-135deg);
}
.out:after{
    left:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;

    -webkit-transform : rotate(315deg);
    transform : rotate(315deg);
}
.in:after{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:#911618;
    z-index:-1;
}
video{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Ooooh - that's almost 100% perfect. Is there a way to remove the bottom rectangle block?

Comment: You mean the red rectangle? I can try

Comment: Yes, that's right, it's very faint, but it would be good to delete completely :-)

Comment: To do that change the .in height to 100% ;) [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/4DayJ/)

Comment: You too :D I'm glad to help

Comment: Good spot @Ninita, +1

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you have done is put the video as the top element and reduced the opacity to show items behind it.

what you would need to do is change the following 2 values on the bottom and left/right shapes.

```
z-index: 20;
opacity: 0.5;
```

After doing this though as the bottom 1 is a whole block, it covers the whole video, may have to rethink your shapes, or use an image overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcLkW/21/

Comment: This is *very* close, Khyam - can you think of a better way so the bottom block isn't solid like that? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need just set the triangle to top layer, because now the block "DIV.inn" is under video, and you see it through transparent video.

Change your code like:

**CSS**

```
.out:before, .out:after, .in:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:25%;
width:100%;
height:700%;
background-color:#9A4445;
z-index:1000;
```

}

Comment: Using that code, I get this result: http://jsfiddle.net/fcLkW/22/ which isn't great as I appear to lose the transparency on the other 3 shapes.

Comment: Sorry, this is my low English. I mixed triangles ))